# Index creation in multiple tablespaces in db2

Tags: indexing, db2

I have a basic question.
In db2, is it possible to create an index which resides in multiple table spaces?
Just like we can create a partitioned table in multiple tablespaces?

I tried a couple of links from IBM.
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0021581.html

Is there a way we can make an index reside in multiple tablespaces?

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes.  FYI, the [page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0021581.html) that you linked to provides the answer to your question.

When you create a partitioned index on a range-partitioned table, the index partition for each table partition can reside in a different tablespace.  See [Figure 3](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0021581.html#c0021581__partindex) for a picture of how this looks.